# Is it necessary to have toString() in an enum in Java?

Tags: java, enums

I don't think we can instantiate an Enum. So do we need to have toString(), equals() and hashCode() method for an enum? Is this statement true?

Also as a follow up question
What does "this" keyword refers to in the following enum class?

```
public enum DocuType {
       text, print, html, pdf; //Why aren't these in caps? 

       public boolean isPrint() {return this == print; }  //What does this refers to?
       public boolean isText() {return this == text; }

       public boolean isTextOrPrint() { return isText() || isPrint(); }
}
```

How do I call any of the boolean methods of this enum as they are not static?
Also when I call, what does the keyword "this" refers to ?

Comment: Ask **one** question/question.

Comment: I recommend going through the `enum` tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: You never *need* to supply a `toString`. You can just override the base implementation if you need pretty printing.

Comment: *"Why aren't these in caps?"* Because whoever wrote that code didn't following Java naming conventions. Whether they felt they knew better (didn't feel like following the standard way of naming things), or they didn't know at all (didn't know that naming conventions even existed), is unknown.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did go through that. It doesn't say anything about toString( ) method. Also I am still confused if Enum is a special class or a data type. Because the link says its a data type. But only for a class we can have constructors. I am totally a newbie and I don;t know what is meant by datatype. Its been just 48 hours I started learning Java.

Comment: @Andreas Yep, I realized that. I gonna tell it to the owner of the code.

Comment: @Carcigenicate What you meant by supplying toString( ) , but overriding base implementation.

Comment: @SamtthaBiby Data type is just general for both primitive types (e.g. `int` or `double`) and reference types (e.g. `String` or `File`). An `enum` is a reference type.

Comment: @SamtthaBiby You asked "So do we need to have toString(), equals() and hashCode()". You never *need* to have any of those methods; a default is given by the `Object` base class; which I'm guessing Enum inherit from. You only write your own version if you need specific behavior.

Comment: Re, "I don't think we can instantiate an Enum."  Correct.  You can not write code to create _new_ instances, but that does not mean that there are _no_ instances.  Each of the enum constants that you declare is a reference to a different instance of the class.

Comment: An `enum` is a `class` that implicitly extends [`java.lang.Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html), and hence inherits methods like [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString--) from `Enum`, and the javadoc says: *`toString()` returns the name of this enum constant, as contained in the declaration. This method **may be overridden, though it typically isn't necessary or desirable**. An enum type should override this method when a more "programmer-friendly" string form exists.*

Comment: @SamtthaBiby: From that tutorial: *"The enum declaration **defines a class** (called an enum type)."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't think we can instantiate an Enum.

Enum is one of type as we have class type. The way we can create instance (i.e. create variable) of a class, similarly we can create variables of Enum but that's only during during its definition which eventually makes them a Constant.

> So do we need to have toString(), equals() and hashCode() method for an enum?

equals() & hashcode() are used to compare two instances. In case of class instances, the instances are created dynamically. So this means we don't have knowledge about instances beforehand and hence we need to compare them to know if they are equal. However, in case of Enum we know the instances when we define the Enum. So, we know beforehand whether they are equal or not. If the enum instances mean to be equal why on the earth we need two separate equal enum instances. So, in case of enum we generally don't override these methods.

> What does "this" keyword refers to in the following enum class?

&

> How do I call any of the boolean methods of this enum as they are not static?

&

> Also when I call, what does the keyword "this" refers to ?

*this* means an instance currently in access. In your example, you have *DocuType* instances as text, pdf, print, html. When you invoke a method on any of the instance, ex: DocuType.text.isPrint(), *this* keyword inside the *isPrint* method will point to *text*. So, for instance pdf, all the methods will return false except isPdf().

Answer (score 2):

> So do we need to have toString(), equals() and hashCode() method for an enum? Is this statement true?

You don't need any of these methods in the enum.

> Also as a follow up question What does "this" keyword refers to in the following enum class?

Imagine you have this code:

```
DocuType myType = DocuType.print;
```

If you want to check if the document is a PRINT document, you can do this:

```
boolean isPrint = myType.isPrint();
```

In this case, `this` is the `myType`, which means that it's the `print` enum. In the end, the result is `true`, because print == print;

Answer (score 1):

**I would also suggest to read the [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) to Enums**

It seems you lack the knowledge of the concept of an enum.

And to your last question, an enum is static, but each "type" of it is an object, meaning you can do

```
DocuType.html.isText(); // false
DocuType.print.isPrint(); // true
```

To initalize your own Enum you have to

```
DocuType TextDocu = DocuType.text;
```

And you can write them in CAPS, but you don't have to, but it's recommened.
To explain it more in detail:

```
enum DocuType //this is an enum and not instantiatable
text,print,html,pdf // these are Objects with the functions of the enum and are an instance
```

Comment: Thanks. Sure, I will go through the tutorials. The problem with self learning is no in person guru to teach or guide and I have to seek help online. Can we say that DocuType myType = DocuType.print;  is the way to instantiate an enum?

Answer (score 0):

As preparation for an explanation, a quick glance back in history.
Before enums were available in Java, a possible replacement could have been constructed like that:

```
public class DocuType {
   public final static DocuType text=new DocuType();
   public final static DocuType print=new DocuType();
   public final static DocuType html=new DocuType();
   public final static DocuType pdf=new DocuType();

   private DocuType(){}; // hide constructor

   public boolean isPrint() {return this == print; }
   public boolean isText() {return this == text; }

   public boolean isTextOrPrint() { return isText() || isPrint(); }
}
```

As you can see, while you cannot create new instances of DocuType, 4 static instances of them are already prepared for you in the Class.

Javas enum work very similar to that example (less writing involved, obviously); therefore, `this` refers to the instance you execute the method on. Regarding `toString`, it's up to you; the default implementation can be good enough or not. There is no need to implement neither `equals` nor `hashCode`.

Comment: Great explanation. There is no need to implement neither equals nor hashCode. May I know why?

Comment: Since you cannot have two different instances of an enum that have to considered equal,  all you need for `equal` is object identity. Which is default. Similary, you do not have to worry that two different instances, logically considered equal,  produce different `hashCode()`s, which would create problems in `HashMap`s etc. Since the only kind of equallity is identity, that can't happen. (Maybe two different instances produce the same hashCode, but that is generally not a problem)